# Is there a way to init a C double with a const value based on a hex pattern?

Tags: c, constants, c99

I have a need to put an invalid hex pattern into a C-99 `double` value.

Unfortunately, this does not work (for obvious reasons):

```
const double invalid_double = 0x7ff0000000000001;
```

Neither does this (because the deref of the int const isn't know to be const apparently)

```
const uint64_t invalid_int = 0x7ff0000000000001;
const double invalid_double =  *(((double*)&invalid_int);
```

And `union` init does not seem to help much either (because `u.d` is not considered compile time const):

```
union {
  double d;
  uint64_t i;
} const u = { .i = 0x7ff0000000000001 };


const double invalid_double =  u.d;
```

Is there a way? I know invalid `double` are undefined behaviour and that I am walking into strange territory here. But, I have a special use case for this value.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251422/discussion-on-question-by-thomas-kejser-is-there-a-way-to-init-a-c-double-with-a).

Comment: @ThomasKejser How are you planning on *using* this sentinel value, assuming you can initialize it? If you have some other double value `x`, then the expression `x == invalid_double` is *always* going to return false, even if `x` actually does have the sentinel value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use compiler extensions, for example GCC has `__builtin_nan` and `__builtin_nans` functions for quiet and signaling NaN respectively.

```
const double invalid_double = __builtin_nans("1");  // 0x7ff0000000000001
```

It's not C99, but better to fail predictably if compiler doesn't support it, than fail unpredictably with some hacky solution.

You could also define your own NaN macro, which uses this builtin function on GCC, but reverts to standard NAN macro for other compilers.

Comment: This only allows valid NAN though, or ?

Comment: @ThomasKejser I don't understand your question. It gives you NaN with significant value of your choosing. What would invalid NAN be like?

Comment: @ThomasKejser All NaNs are "invalid".  But facilities like `__builtin_nans()` let you construct any NaN (that is, a NaN with any payload) that you choose.  `__builtin_nans("1")` requests a payload of 1, which I believe will end up matching your desired bit pattern `0x7ff0000000000001`.

Comment: Specifically, in IEEE 754, a NaN is a value with a raw exponent of `0x7ff` and a nonzero significand — that is, *any* nonzero significand.  In double precision, there are actually 2⁵²-1 = 4,503,599,627,370,495 different NaN values.  They're all just about equivalently "invalid", although there is an (imperfectly defined) distinction between "signaling" and "non-signaling".

Comment: @SteveSummit by "invalid Nan" i mean one that cannot be generate by any floating point operation. If the builtin allows me to construct any payload, I think that actually does the trick

Comment: @ThomasKejser I understand, although I have to caution you, "one that cannot be generated by any floating point operation" is probably not something you can perfectly guarantee.  Theoretically, a floating-point operation can generate any NaN value.

Comment: The intent of that "payload" (or, one of the intents, anyway) is that, theoretically, if you call a function that calls a function that calls a function that generates a NaN, and the NaN percolates all the way back out to a calling function that notices it, the failing f.p. operation can literally stuff the *program counter* and/or other debugging information into the NaN payload, and this could be a huge help in debugging the source of the NaN, if unexpected.

Comment: @SteveSummit thanks. I didn't know that the payload can be used in this manner. Does that actually occur on x64/x86/arm - or is this a hypotetical scenario?

Comment: @ThomasKejser I haven't encountered a platform that does it, and I don't know of any that do.  I assume there are some, but I don't know if they're super rare, or at all widespread, or what.

Comment: Even though this is an extension, I think this is the closest we can get to a nice solution for this problems.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not possible.

Och, who am I kidding! Just write a preprocessor parser of a IEE745 number that would generate a floating point constant expression by preprocessing that number. The following code allows you to do:

```
const double invalid_double = HEX_TO_DOUBLE(0x7ff0000000000001);
```

Note that the `EXPONENT_TO_DOUBLE_IN` macro is lacking about 2000 cases, so not all numbers are handled, but it's easy to fill up. Or maybe someone will have a better idea how to convert exponent to 2^(exponent-1023).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

// Apply function f on argument x and number
#define FOREACH_52(f, x) \
    f(x, 52) f(x, 51) f(x, 50) f(x, 49) f(x, 48) f(x, 47) f(x, 46) f(x, 45) \
    f(x, 44) f(x, 43) f(x, 42) f(x, 41) f(x, 40) f(x, 39) f(x, 38) f(x, 37) \
    f(x, 36) f(x, 35) f(x, 34) f(x, 33) f(x, 32) f(x, 31) f(x, 30) f(x, 29) \
    f(x, 28) f(x, 27) f(x, 26) f(x, 25) f(x, 24) f(x, 23) f(x, 22) f(x, 21) \
    f(x, 20) f(x, 19) f(x, 18) f(x, 17) f(x, 16) f(x, 15) f(x, 14) f(x, 13) \
    f(x, 12) f(x, 11) f(x, 10) f(x, 9) f(x, 8) f(x, 7) f(x, 6) f(x, 5) \
    f(x, 4) f(x, 3) f(x, 2) f(x, 1)

#define EXPONENT_TO_DOUBLE_CASE(x, y)  \
    x == (unsigned long long) y ? 0x1p ##y : \
    x == (unsigned long long)-y ? 0x1p-##y :
#define EXPONENT_TO_DOUBLE_IN(x)  ( \
    EXPONENT_TO_DOUBLE_CASE(x, 1022) \
    EXPONENT_TO_DOUBLE_CASE(x, 1021) \
    EXPONENT_TO_DOUBLE_CASE(x, 127) \
    EXPONENT_TO_DOUBLE_CASE(x, 2) \
    EXPONENT_TO_DOUBLE_CASE(x, 1) \
    EXPONENT_TO_DOUBLE_CASE(x, 0) \
    /* TODO: add more cases*/ \
    NAN )
// Convert EXPONENT number to 2^(x - 1023) number
#define EXPONENT_TO_DOUBLE(x)  EXPONENT_TO_DOUBLE_IN(x - 1023)

#define FRACTION_TO_DOUBLE_CASE(x, n) \
    ( (x & (1ull << (52 - n))) ? 0x1p-##n : 0 ) +
// Convert FRACTION to 0.FRACTION_BITS(2) number.
#define FRACTION_TO_DOUBLE(x)  ( \
    FOREACH_52(FRACTION_TO_DOUBLE_CASE, x) \
    0 )

// Convert sign, exponent and fraction into a hex number.
#define HEX_TO_DOUBLE_IN(SIGN, EXP, FRAC) \
    EXP == 0x7FF ? \
        FRAC == 0 ? \
            SIGN * INFINITY : \
            NAN : \
    SIGN * EXPONENT_TO_DOUBLE(EXP) * ( \
        EXP == 0 ? \
            FRAC == 0 ? \
                0 : \
                (0.0 + FRACTION_TO_DOUBLE(FRAC)) : \
        (1.0 + FRACTION_TO_DOUBLE(FRAC)) \
    )

// The basic conversion utilities.
#define HEX_TO_DOUBLE_SIGN(x)      (((x) & 0x8000000000000000ull) ? -1.0 : 1.0)
#define HEX_TO_DOUBLE_EXPONENT(x)  (((x) & 0x7FF0000000000000ull) >> 52ull)
#define HEX_TO_DOUBLE_FRACTION(x)  (((x) & 0x000fffffffffffffull))
#define HEX_TO_DOUBLE(x)  \
    HEX_TO_DOUBLE_IN( \
        HEX_TO_DOUBLE_SIGN(x), \
        HEX_TO_DOUBLE_EXPONENT(x), \
        HEX_TO_DOUBLE_FRACTION(x) \
    )

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */

union conv { uint64_t i; double d; };
static int err = 0;
void test(const char *str, union conv u, double d) {
    int equal = (isnan(d) && isnan(u.d)) || u.d == d;
    fprintf(stderr,
        "%s if %s is %#"PRIx64" = %g,%a =? %g,%a\n",
        equal ? "   OK" : "ERROR",
        str, u.i, u.d, u.d, d, d
    );
    err += !equal;
}
// Test the conversion.
#define TEST(x) do { \
        static const double mydouble = HEX_TO_DOUBLE(x); \
        test(#x, (union conv){x}, mydouble); \
    } while(0)

int main() {
    assert(HEX_TO_DOUBLE_EXPONENT(0x3FF0000000000000) == 0x3FF);
    assert(FRACTION_TO_DOUBLE(0) == 0);
    assert(FRACTION_TO_DOUBLE(1) == 0x1p-52);
    assert(FRACTION_TO_DOUBLE(0x2) == 0x1p-51);
    assert(FRACTION_TO_DOUBLE(0x3) == 0x1p-51 + 0x1p-52);
    TEST(0x3FF0000000000000);
    TEST(0x3FF0000000000001);
    TEST(0x3FF0000000000101);
    TEST(0x3FFabcdef1234567);
    TEST(0xFFF0000000000000);
    TEST(0x7FF0000000000000);
    TEST(0x7FF0000000000001);

    // Finally, the test.
    static const double invalid_double = HEX_TO_DOUBLE(0x7ff0000000000001);
    assert(isnan(invalid_double));

    return err;
}
```

When compiled with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` outputs the code from `test()` function that I used for unit testing.

```
   OK if 0x3FF0000000000000 is 0x3ff0000000000000 = 1,0x1p+0 =? 1,0x1p+0
   OK if 0x3FF0000000000001 is 0x3ff0000000000001 = 1,0x1.0000000000001p+0 =? 1,0x1.0000000000001p+0
   OK if 0x3FF0000000000101 is 0x3ff0000000000101 = 1,0x1.0000000000101p+0 =? 1,0x1.0000000000101p+0
   OK if 0x3FFabcdef1234567 is 0x3ffabcdef1234567 = 1.67111,0x1.abcdef1234567p+0 =? 1.67111,0x1.abcdef1234567p+0
   OK if 0xFFF0000000000000 is 0xfff0000000000000 = -inf,-inf =? -inf,-inf
   OK if 0x7FF0000000000000 is 0x7ff0000000000000 = inf,inf =? inf,inf
   OK if 0x7FF0000000000001 is 0x7ff0000000000001 = nan,nan =? nan,nan
```

Additional cases of `NAN("1")` etc. can be also handled with an if-case, like `#define FRACTION_TO_NAN(x)  x == 0 ? __builtin_nan("0") : x == 1 ? __builtin_nan("1") ...` however, I do not think that will be compilable.

Anyway, it's not possible to convert hex to double in `static`. And for `NAN` with special fraction, you have to use compiler extensions anyway, see answer by user694733 .

Comment: This is pretty impressive. However, doesn't last test case `0x7FF0000000000001` result actually in quiet NaN rather than signaling NaN (highest bit of significant is set), considering that standard macro `NAN` should be quiet? (I haven't actually tested)

Answer (score 0):

This will probably work, but it relies on undefined behavior and so cannot be recommended:

In file `consts.c`:

```
#include <stdint.h>

const uint32_t x = 0x420a0000UL;
const uint64_t y = 0x408edd0000000000ULL;
```

In file `main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern const float x;
extern const double y;

int main()
{
    printf("%f %f\n", x, y);
}
```

On my machine, at least, this prints

```
34.500000 987.625000
```

as intended.  And if I use Thomas Kejser's bit pattern `0x7ff0000000000001`  I get `nan`.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it cannot be done now. Upcoming C23 will allow it by adding `constexpr` storage specifier. For now I suggest using a union combined with a macro.

```
union {
  double d;
  uint64_t i;
} const u = { .i = 0x7ff0000000000001 };

#define invalid_double (u.d)

int main() {
    printf("%g", invalid_double);
}
```

prints:

```
nan
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an alternative?  Initialize with a *pointer* to `double`?

```
const double *const invalid_double_ptr = &( union {
      double d;
      uint64_t i;
    }) {.i = 0x7ff0000000000001}.d;
```

---

Note: `union` exploit assumes `sizeof(double) == sizeof(uint64_t)`, both members have the same endian, and `double` using expected encoding.