# Write double bitpattern as a literal

Tags: c

I have the hex literal 400D99999999999A which is the bitpattern for 3.7 as
a double
How do I write this in C? I saw [this
page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal) about
floating_literal and hex. Maybe it's obvious and I need to sleep but I'm
not seeing how to write the bitpattern as a float. I understand it's
suppose to let a person write a more precise fraction but I'm not sure how
to translate a bitpattern to a literal

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double d = 0x400D99999999999Ap0;
    printf("%f\n", d); //incorrect
    
    unsigned long l = 0x400D99999999999A;
    memcpy(&d, &l, 8);
    printf("%f\n", d); //correct, 3.7
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your bit pattern probably encodes the exponent bits — your hex floating point literal will encode those via the exponent (the `p0` in your example.  There's also the sign bit for the mantissa to deal with.  I'd need to investigate whether the 'assumed 1-bit' is presented in the hex floating point literal; it probably is.  So, you'll need to do some thinking to remove the exponent and sign bits from the hex stream, and then encode the rest properly.  You could find out more by printing `3.7` using the `%A` format — which prints the hex representation for the value.

Comment: `0x400D99999999999Ap0;` does not specify the hexadecimal bit pattern for a double.  It just gives the value as a hex value and a power-of-two exponent.  For example, `0xAp1` is the floating point value `20.0`.  The `A` portion has the value 10, and the exponent of 1 multiplies it by 2.  2*10 = 20.  It's not a way to specify an IEEE bit pattern.

Comment: I disagree, @TomKarzes, but there's no particular point in fighting it out in the comments.  A lot depends on what the first sentence _"I have the hex literal 400D99999999999A which is the bit pattern for 3.7 as a double"_ means.  I agree that the attempted hex floating point constant bears no resemblance to the value `3.7`.  I've not checked what the bit pattern for the value 3.7 actually is.  But I think that the OP is saying that the 8-byte sequence for the value 3.7 contains the bytes shown.  I may be wrong — in which case I regard the question as ambiguous.

Comment: @TomKarzes — Yes, but you're fixating on the code and I'm fixating on the question.  The two are not very closely related!  On a little-endian machine (x86_64 and arm64 tested), the bit pattern for the 8 bytes of a `double` holding `3.7` as a series of hex digits are `9A 99 99 99 99 99 0D 40`.  The OP may be on a big-endian machine since their bit pattern is in the reverse order.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler good point.  I read the question more carefully, and posted an answer with the correct value to produce the desired bit pattern.

Comment: If you print `3.7` using conversion specification `%13.12A`, you probably get the output `0X1.D9999999999AP+1`.  If you use `%14.13A`, you get an extra 9 (`0X1.D99999999999AP+1`); if you use `%15.14A`, you get a zero after the `A`, `0X1.D99999999999A0P+1`, and going beyond that yields more zeros.

Comment: Some ideas at [Is there a way to init a C double with a const value based on a hex pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75245099)

Comment: You probably knew this, but just in case: `400D99999999999A` does not represent *exactly* 3.7; it's more like 3.7000000000000001776 (plus about 30 more digits).

Answer (score 4):

> how to write the bitpattern as a float.

The bit pattern 0x400D99999999999A commonly encodes (alternates encodings exists) the `double` with a value of about 3.7<sup>*1</sup>.

```
double d;
unsigned long l = 0x400D99999999999A;
// Assume same size, same endian
memcpy(&d, &l, 8);
printf("%g\n", d);
// output 3.7
```

To write the value out using `"%a"` format with a hexadecimal significand, decimal power-of-2 exponent

```
printf("%g\n", d);
// output 0x1.d99999999999ap+1
```

The `double` *constant* (not *literal*) `1.d99999999999ap+1` has an explicit 1 bit and  and the lower 52-bits of `0x400D99999999999A` and the exponent of `+1` is like the biased exponent bits (12 most significant bits, expect the sign bit) biased by 0x400 - 1.

Now code can use `double d  = 0x1.d99999999999ap+1` instead of the `memcpy()` to initialize `d`.

---

<sup>*1</sup> Closest `double` to 3.7 is exactly
3.70000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125

Answer (score 3):

The value you're trying to use is an IEEE bit pattern.  C doesn't support this directly.  To get the desired bit pattern, you need to specify the mantissa, as an ordinary hex integer, along with a power-of-two exponent.

In this case, the desired IEEE bit pattern is `400D99999999999A`.  If you strip off the sign bit and the exponent, you're left with `D99999999999A`.  There's an implied leading `1` bit, so to get the actual mantissa value, that needs to be explicitly added, giving `1D99999999999A`.  This represents the mantissa as an integer with no fractional part.  It then needs to be scaled, in this case by a power-of-two exponent value of -51.  So the desired constant is:

```
    double d = 0x1D99999999999Ap-51;
```

If you plug this into your code, you will get the desired bit pattern of `400D99999999999A`.

Answer (score 3):

The following program shows how to interpret a string of bits as a `double`, using either the native `double` format or using the IEEE-754 double-precision binary format (binary64).

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>


//  Create a mask of n bits, in the low bits.
#define Mask(n) (((uint64_t) 1 << (n)) - 1)


/*  Given a uint64_t containing 64 bits, this function interprets them in the
    native double format.
*/
double InterpretNativeDouble(uint64_t bits)
{
    double result;
    _Static_assert(sizeof result == sizeof bits, "double must be 64 bits");

    //  Copy the bits into a native double.
    memcpy(&result, &bits, sizeof result);

    return result;
}


/*  Given a uint64_t containing 64 bits, this function interprets them in the
    IEEE-754 double-precision binary format.  (Checking that the native double
    format has sufficient bounds and precision to represent the result is
    omitted.  For NaN results, a NaN is returned, but the signaling
    characteristic and the payload bits are not supported.)
*/
double InterpretDouble(uint64_t bits)
{
    /*  Set some parameters of the format.  (This routine is not fully
        parameterized for all IEEE-754 binary formats; some hardcoded constants
        are used.)
    */
    static const int Emax      = 1023;  //  Maximum exponent.
    static const int Precision =   53;  //  Precision (number of digits).

    //  Separate the fields in the encoding.
    int SignField             = bits >> 63;
    int ExponentField         = bits >> 52 & Mask(11);
    uint64_t SignificandField = bits & Mask(52);

    //  Interpret the exponent and significand fields.
    int Exponent;
    double Significand;

    switch (ExponentField)
    {
        /*  An exponent field of all zero bits indicates a subnormal number,
            for which the exponent is fixed at its minimum and the leading bit
            of the significand is zero.  This includes zero, which is not
            classified as a subnormal number but is consistent in the encoding.
        */
        case 0:
            Exponent = 1 - Emax;
            Significand = 0 + ldexp(SignificandField, 1-Precision);
                //  ldexp(x, y) computes x * pow(2, y).
            break;

        /*  An exponent field of all one bits indicates a NaN or infinity,
            according to whether the significand field is zero or not.
        */
        case Mask(11):
            Exponent = 0;
            Significand = SignificandField ? NAN : INFINITY;
            break;

        /*  All other exponent fields indicate normal numbers, for which the
            exponent is encoded with a bias (equal to EMax) and the leading bit
            of the significand is one.
        */
        default:
            Exponent = ExponentField - Emax;
            Significand = 1 + ldexp(SignificandField, 1-Precision);
            break;
    }

    //  Combine the exponent and significand,.
    Significand = ldexp(Significand, Exponent);

    //  Interpret the sign field.
    if (SignField)
        Significand = -Significand;

    return Significand;
}


#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>


int main(void)
{
    uint64_t bits = 0x400D99999999999A;

    printf("The bits 0x%16" PRIx64 " interpreted as:\n", bits);
    printf("\ta native double represent %.9999g, and\n",
        InterpretNativeDouble(bits));
    printf("\tan IEEE-754 double-precision datum represent %.9999g.\n",
        InterpretDouble(bits));
}
```

Comment: I think you need the equivalent of `if(InterpretNativeDouble(bits) != InterpretDouble(bits)) printf("Jackpot!\n");` in there somewhere.  And I am in awe of your facile deployment of `%.9999g`, a format string which I am quite certain I have never seen before. :-)

Comment: @SteveSummit Given "Environmental limits The number of characters that can be produced by any single conversion shall be at least 4095." C17dr § 7.21.6.1 15, conversion wider than that may fail.  `%.9999g` takes the idea of printing the `double` very precisely, yet runs into that library limitation.  IAC, how good `double` to text conversion much beyond `DECIMAL_DIG` digits runs into quality of implementation issues too.  I agree that its is novel to see `%.9999g`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: `%.9999g` will not hit the 4095 bound. With IEEE-754 binary64, it will produce at most 774 characters, for −2^−1022+2^−1074, for which the digits start with a 2 at the 10^−308 position and end with a 5 at the 10^−1074 position, taking 1074−308+1 = 767 digits, plus "-”, “.”, and “e-308”, making 774.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I suppose you mean something like [2.225073858507201...e-308](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/212490/29485).  True, yet that supposes that the `printf()` is good enough to get the ultra precise conversion right and that `double` is binary64.  If we assume those, then `%.800g` would have been more than sufficient and not an environmental limit risk, otherwise the possible outputs are less restrictive.  IAC nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

As an [IEEE-754 double-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) value, that bit pattern `400D99999999999A` actually consists of three parts:

- the first bit, 0, is the *sign*;
- the next 11 bits, `10000000000` or `0x400`, are the *exponent*; and
- the remaining 52 bits, `0xD99999999999A`, are the *significand* (also known as the "mantissa").

But the exponent has a bias of 1023 (`0x3ff`), so numerically it's `0x400` - `0x3ff` = 1.  And the significand is all fractional, and has an implicit 1 bit to its left, so it's really `0x1.D99999999999A`.

So the actual number this represents is

```
0x1.D99999999999A × 2¹
```

which is about 1.85 × 2, or 3.7.

Or, using C's "hex float" or `%a` representation, it's `0x1.D99999999999Ap1`.

In "hex float" notation, the leading `1` and the decimal point (really a "radix point") are explicit, and the `p` at the end indicates a power-of-two exponent.

Although the decomposition I've shown here may seem reasonably straightforward, actually writing code to reliably decompose a 64-bit number like `400D99999999999A` into its three component parts, and manipulate and recombine them to determine what floating-point value they represent (or even to form an equivalent hex float constant like `0x1.D99999999999Ap1`) can be surprisingly tricky.  See [Eric Postpischil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75332166#75335682) for more of the details.